# How to establish Socket Connection between Mobile device and Server

Tags: tcp, ip-address

For TCP Socket, the Server is connected to the Client through the Socket.

But if the client is a mobile phone, and because its IP address keep changing would that break the socket between it and the server?

From the Server point of view, does it care the IP addressed of the Client?

Comment: Does the server needs to know the IP address of the Mobile Client?

Comment: From alot example seem like Only the Client needs to know the IP and Port address of the Server but Not the other ways around.

Comment: But for Mobile phone, people are always on the go, the IP address keep changing.  Let's say a person established a socket and then he moved elsewhere he doesn't even know he needs to make a new connect() call in the code. he doesn't know IP got changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TCP/IP, server need not know client's IP address.Its client which should know server's ip address and connect itself .Whenever IP will be changed for client,client will have next connect() and server will have next accept() call.

Comment: But for Mobile phone, people are always on the go, the IP address keep changing.  Let's say a person established a socket and then he moved elsewhere he doesn't even know he needs to make a new connect() call in the code. he doesn't know IP got changed.

Comment: TCP can be configured so as the client with multiple IP address remain bound to the same port no and server always listen to the same port.